# Kibana infinite data visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, kibana-5

How much data Kibana or ELK can handle? I have CSV file which has infinite data nd its growing day by day. I want to load it in Kibana for visualization.
Can someone tell me how much data ELK can handle?

Comment: This depends entirely on your elasticsearch cluster configuration. Usually the constraining resource is memory. ES scales very well. You could check out the [sizing docs](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-sizing-elasticsearch) or [this blog post about a petabyte-scale ES cluster](https://grey-boundary.io/field-notes-elasticsearch-at-petabyte-scale-on-aws/).

Answer (score 0):

Kibana is quite good in working with large datasets, so the limiting factor in your case is elasticsearch. As long as you can scale your elasticsearch cluster, you can store quite a large amount of data on it, but please remember that you need an infinitely large cluster to store "infinite" amount of data. That could be quite costly :)